# Angular2, Firebase, AngularFire2, route guard and how to deal with subscription

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have a route guard that works for now but I get this message:

```
WARNING: the getAuth() API has changed behavior since adding support for Firebase 3.
    This will return null for the initial value when the page loads, even if the user is actually logged in.
    Please observe the actual authState asynchronously by subscribing to the auth service: af.auth.subscribe().
    The getAuth method will be removed in future releases
```

Here is my current guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class AuthFirebaseGuard implements CanActivate {

  user={}
  constructor(public af: AngularFire,
              private router: Router
              ) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot){

    if (this.af.auth.getAuth().uid){
        return true;
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
    }

  }
}
```

Here is what I want to change to:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthFirebaseGuard implements CanActivate {

  user={}
  constructor(public af: AngularFire,
              private router: Router
              ) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
              state: RouterStateSnapshot){


    this.user = this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
              if (user) {
                        this.user = user.auth.providerData[0];
                        if (user.auth.emailVerified==false){
                        user.auth.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
                            this.router.navigate(['login']);
                            return false;
                        });
                        } else {
                           return true;
                        }
              }
              else {
                this.router.navigate(['login']);
                return false;
              }
            }); 
  }
}
```

How do I wait for the subscription to complete?

```
Class 'AuthFirebaseGuard' incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.
  Types of property 'canActivate' are incompatible.
    Type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => boolean | Observable<boolean> | Pr...'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>'.








ERROR in [default] /Users/Documents/frontend/iboot/src/app/common/auth-firebase.gaurd.ts:14:13 
Class 'AuthFirebaseGuard' incorrectly implements interface 'CanActivate'.
  Types of property 'canActivate' are incompatible.
    Type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => boolean | Observable<boolean> | Pr...'.
      Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>'.
        Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<boolean>'.
          Property 'then' is missing in type 'Observable<{}>'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/Documents/frontend/iboot/src/app/common/auth-firebase.gaurd.ts:41:40 
Argument of type 'firebase.Promise<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<any>'.
  Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
    Type '(onResolve?: (a: any) => any, onReject?: (a: Error) => any) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type '{ <TResult1, TResult2>(onfulfilled: (value: any) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>, onrejected:...'.
      Type 'firebase.Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`canActivate` can return a boolean, a promise or an observable, so you can compose an observable using AngularFire2's `auth` observable:

```
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
) {

  return this.af.auth

    // Observables returned by canActivate have to complete, so take the
    // first emitted value from the auth observable.

    .first()

    // Use mergeMap to project the values emitted from the inner
    // observables created using Observable.fromPromise and
    // Observable.of. (If you weren't making the call to
    // sendEmailVerification, you could just use the map operator
    // and would return a boolean.)

    .mergeMap((user) => {

      if (user && user.auth) {
        if (!user.auth.emailVerified) {
          return Observable.fromPromise(user.auth
            .sendEmailVerification()
            .then(() => {
              this.router.navigate(['login']);
              return false;
            })
          );
        }
        return Observable.of(true);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return Observable.of(false);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: I added the error message I get when trying your solution

Comment: I took out the logic of .sendEmailVerification() and it worked.  Don't need it anyway.  Thanks!

Comment: No worries. The error sounds like a TypeScript issue with duck-typed promises. You could cast it to appease TypeScript: `...sendEmailVerification().then(() => ... ) as Promise<any>`